# How do you say "sweater" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

In [ESPDIC](http://www.denisowski.org/Esperanto/Esperanto.html) I found some suggestions for a translation of the English word *sweater*: svetro, svetero, ĵerzo, pulovro, trikoto, and trikotvesto; some of these may be found on [Vortaro](http://vortaro.net/), but none of them have particularly accurate-seeming definitions, and none of them have [Vikipedio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vikipedio:%C4%88efpa%C4%9Do) entries. Which of these, or perhaps which other word, is the most fitting translation for the English word *sweater*?

---

En [ESPDIC](http://www.denisowski.org/Esperanto/Esperanto.html) mi trovis kelkajn sugestajn tradukojn de la angla vorto *sweater*: svetro, svetero, ĵerzo, pulovro, trikoto, kaj trikotvesto; kelkaj el ĉi tiuj troveblas en [Vortaro](http://vortaro.net/), sed neniuj el ili havas difinon tre akuratŝajnan, kaj neniuj el ili havas enigon en [Vikipedio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vikipedio:%C4%88efpa%C4%9Do). Kiuj el ĉi tiuj, aŭ eble alia vorto, estas la plej taŭga traduko por la angla vorto *sweater*?

Answer (score 3):

*svetro* is quiet common in colloquial language according to my experience. However *pulovero* is more often found in dictionaries (vortaro, revo).

Comment: So is svetro really used in practice? I used to think it was just a misspelling of svetero, because this is how it appears in dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

> Svetero = Malformala torsovesto el mola ŝtofo. http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/sveter.html#sveter.0o

Non-formal garment, worn over the torso, made of soft fabric.

Answer (score 3):

While *svetero* is listed in PIV, I can't say I've ever heard it in use. There are no hits for this word in Tekstaro.

***Pulovero*** is in common use (both in Tekstaro and according to my personal impression), and is also listed in PIV